# Group Rallygrid by Milestones

Tags: rally

Hello I am trying to group US/Defects by milestones they are assigned to. Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?
I can group by owner or project, but having issues grouping by milestone.

```js
this.add({
                        xtype: 'rallygrid',
                        columnCfgs: [
                            'FormattedID',
                            'Name',
                            'State',
                            'Owner',
                            'Milestones'
                        ],
                        context: this.getContext(),
                        features: [{
                            ftype: 'groupingsummary',
                            groupHeaderTpl: '{name} ({rows.length})'
                        }],
                        storeConfig: {
                            models: ['User Story', 'Defect'],
                            groupField: 'Milestones',
                            groupDir: 'ASC',
                         /*  filters : [
                                {
                                  property : 'State',
                                  operator : '!=',
                                  value : 'Closed'
                                }
                            ],*/
                            fetch: ['Milestones'],
                            getGroupString: function(record) {
                                var Milestones = record.get('Milestones');
                                return (Milestones && Milestones._refObjectName) || 'No Milestones';
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tricky one.  This is what I came up with:

```
this.add({
    xtype: 'rallygrid',
    columnCfgs: [
        'FormattedID',
        'Name',
        'State',
        'Owner',
        'Milestones'
    ],
    context: this.getContext(),
    features: [{
        ftype: 'groupingsummary',
        groupHeaderTpl: '{name} ({rows.length})'
    }],
    storeConfig: {
        model: 'userstory',
        groupField: 'Milestones',
        listeners: {
            beforeload: function(store) {
                //remove the Milestones sorter, since Milestones
                //is not a sortable field
                var sorter = store.sorters.first();
                if (sorter && sorter.property === store.groupField) {
                    store.sorters.remove(sorter);
                }
            }
        },
        getGroupString: function(record) {
            var milestones = record.get('Milestones');

            //grab the Name field from each object in the _tagsNameArray
            return _.pluck(milestones._tagsNameArray, 'Name').join(',') || 'None';
        }
    }
});
```

There are two main differences from your code.  The first one is the beforeload handler in the storeConfig.  The default behavior of stores is to prepend the groupField into the sorters array.  This is usually what we want, but in this case Milestones is not a sortable field in WSAPI so the request fails.  So we just remove that sorter.

The second change is in the getGroupString function.  Milestones is a collection, so you can't directly use _refObjectName like you would for an object group field like Owner or Parent.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great, Thank helped a lot!